# How to output numbers with leading zeros in JavaScript? (satoshi format)

Tags: javascript, numbers, bitcoin

Is there a way to prepend leading zeros and a dot to numbers so that it results in a string of fixed length?

For example:
1 becomes "0.00000001 BTC".
498 becomes "0.00000498 BTC".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use `/` to divide, then `toFixed()`.
For example:

```
const number = 10;
console.log((number / 100000000).toFixed(8));
```

You can put it in a function:

```
const toZerosNumber = number => (number / 100000000).toFixed(8);
```

And use it with your examples:

```
toZerosNumber(498); // Output: "0.00000498"
toZerosNumber(1); // Output: "0.00000001"
```